# Add key/value pair to object inside an object-Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to add a key/value pair inside an object. My object looks like this:

```
obj = {
   obj1: {
      a: 1,
      b:2,
      c:3
    },
    obj2:{
      a: 1,
      b:2,
      c:3
    },
    obj3:{
      a: 1,
      b:2,
      c:3
    }
}
```

Now above every sub-objects, I want to add a key/value pair, say: `d:4` and it should look like:

```
 obj = {
   obj1: {
      a: 1,
      b:2,
      c:3,
      d:4
    },
    obj2:{
      a: 1,
      b:2,
      c:3,
      d:4
    },
    obj3:{
      a: 1,
      b:2,
      c:3,
      d:4
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one line:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).forEach(p => obj[p].d = 4);
```

Comment: `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()` is the way.

Answer (score 2):

This will do it:

```
for (var o in obj) {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(o)) {
    obj[o]['d'] = 4;
  }
}
```